# Pagination order by in Cakephp

Tags: php

How to fix pagination order by problem in cakephp. My code is here..

```
$testarray = array(010,011,012,013,014,015,001,002,003,004,005,006,007,008,009);

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $testarray,
    'fields' => array('Test.id'),
    'limit' => 10,
    'page' => 1
);

$testpaginate = $this->paginate('Test');
```

I want the output to be like $testarray, but I get the following:

```
array(001,002,003,004,005,006,007,008,009,010)
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$this->paginate = array(
  'conditions' => $testarray,
  'fields' => array('Test.id'),
  'limit' => 10,
  'page' => 1,
  'order' => '',
);
```

You will probably have to resort to an option outside of CakePHP's built in methods.